# Thermal Printers with bundled android SDK?

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-bluetooth, thermal-printer

I'm looking for a receipt printer which can be controlled by android devices over WiFi or Bluetooth. I have found some printers from Bixolon and Epson which have such capability.
I want to if anyone knows other vendors which have receipt printers which support for Android Devices or not? If yes, I will be grateful if you provide the sdk link for it.

 My Main problem for this question is the price, and i want to know other vendors with printers with lower prices fulfilling my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try Star SM-S220i
http://www.starmicronics.com/printer/portable_printers/sm-s220i

it is a relatively cheap thermal printer compared to Epson and Bixolon.

Comment: where is the android SDK for it?